# Update f:param value when the calendar's value is changed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF. I have a problem in updating f:param value using Ajax but nothing is happening. I also tried changing its value to **p:calendar value="#{reportParameter.startPeriod}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"** but still not working.. Below is my code:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel value="Start Period"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:calendar value="#{reportParameter.startPeriod}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
        <p:ajax update="param-startperiod"/>
    </p:calendar>

    <p:outputLabel value="End Period"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:calendar value="#{reportParameter.endPeriod}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
        <p:ajax update="param-endperiod"/>
    </p:calendar>

    <p:outputLabel value=""></p:outputLabel>
    <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/headoffice/BranchEnrollmentReportServlet">
        <f:param id="param-startperiod" name="startperiod" value="01/01/2010"/>
        <f:param id="param-endperiod" name="endperiod" value="10/01/2018"/>
        View
    </h:outputLink>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try updating the outputlink.

Comment: Can you post a code for a sample? Thanks.

Comment: uhhh... what kind of sample? You seem to understand ajax, just do `h:outputLink id="myId"` and `p:ajax update="myId"`